# Are the goods in additively separable utility functions normal goods?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, giffen-goods

Inspired by [this answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/43958/1601).

---

To make it a bit more precise, by normal good I mean demand is (not necessarily strictly) increasing in income, and by additively separable utility function I mean that a monotone transformation exists for which
$$
U(x_1,x_2,\dots) = f_1(x_1) + f_2(x_2) + \dots 
$$
(Also assume $U$ is increasing in all variables.) 
Given a linear budget constraint and a utility maximizing consumer, do these goods $x_i$ exhibit normal behavior for all income levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes if you assume that the sub-utility functions are concave. Notice that this is a standard assumption as otherwise, the utility function $u = \sum_i f_i$ is not guaranteed to be concave (nor quasi-concave).

Let denote by $u_i = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$ and by $u_{i,j} = \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$. By additivity $u_{i,j} = 0$ if $i \ne j$.

The first order conditions for the utility maximisation problem give:
$$
\begin{align*}
u_i = \lambda p_i, \tag{1}\\
\sum_i p_i x_i = m \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Differentiating both with respect to income $m$ (and using $u_{i,j} = 0$) gives:

$$
\begin{align*}
&u_{ii} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m} = p_i \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial m} \tag{3}\\
&\sum_i p_i \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m} = 1 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
$$
Substitute $(3$) into $(4)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_i (p_i)^2 \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial m} \frac{1}{u_{ii}} = 1,\\
\to &\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial m} = \frac{1}{\sum_i \frac{(p_i)^2}{u_{ii}}} \tag{5}
\end{align*}
$$
Notice that $u_{ii} < 0$ by concavity of the sub-utility functions. As such, $\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial m} < 0$ and also, by $(3)$:
$$
\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m} = p_i \frac{1}{u_{ii}} \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial m} > 0 
$$
as the right hand side is the product of two negative numbers.

This shows that $x_i$ is a normal good. By symmetry, this holds for all goods.

An alternative quicker way to notice this is to see that

1. by $(3)$ the sign of $\dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial m}$ will be the reverse of the sign of $\dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial m}$.
2. This has to be true for all goods, which means that either all goods are normal, or all goods are inferior.
3. From $(4)$, it follows that at least one good should be normal (as otherwise the sum cannot be equal to 1 which is greater than zero).
4. Conclude that all goods have to be normal.

Comment: You do not need to assume that $u$ is concave: the utility function is ordinal and the demand functions are unchanged after any monotonic transformation of the utility function.

Comment: @Bertrand I'm not talking about the utility function but the sub-utility functions $f_i$. These better be concave as otherwise $u = \sum_i f_i $ does not even need to be quasi-concave. Notice that although the sum of concave functions is concave, the sum of quasi-concave functions is not necessarily quasi-concave.

Comment: I just wanted to mention that assuming concavity is sufficient not necessary: if all $u_{ii}>0$ the demands are still normal.

Comment: @Bertrand If all sub-utility functions are convex (i.e. $u_{ii} > 0$) then the utility function is (quasi-)convex. In this case, the first order conditions is not going to give you a maximum, but a minimum.

Comment: Lovely! My one comment is that you seem to assume an interior solution by assuming (1) holds in equality. This is of course not guaranteed; usually we also assume $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$. Any ideas on how to handle the boundary case?

Comment: @Giskard I guess you can argue in the following way. If $x_i = 0$ at the optimum and if income increases, then either $x_i$ goes up (to an interior solution), so it is normal, or it stays at $0$ in which case it is also normal (in the weak sense). As $x_i = 0$, it can never go down if income increases.

Comment: I think you could also argue that the right hand side of
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_i p_i \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m} = 1 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
$$
is unchanged if you remove all the indices where $x_i = 0$ and $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m} = 0$, and then your interior solution works again.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how to you arrive at the first order conditions for the utility maximisation problem (1):